# Use [(ngmodel)] value to update value in firestore

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I would like to use this :

```
<ion-col class="champ" width-25 style="margin-right: 20px;">
        <div >
            Nom
        <ion-input placeholder="Dupont" [(ngModel)]="utilisateur.nom" type="text"></ion-input></div>
    </ion-col>
```

So [(ngModel)] come from my database and then I would like to update data like this :

```
EditData(id) {
    this.firestore.collection('users').doc(this.passided).update({
    nom: "a",})
}
```

So here, if I click on edit button nom will be "a" but I would like to use "utilisateur.nom" from ngmodel

Did you have any idea? Thanks.

EDIT

```
this.firestore.collection('users').doc(this.passided).valueChanges().subscribe(data => 
    { 


this.utilisateurs = Array.of(data);
            console.log(data);
console.log(this.utilisateurs);


 });
```

Comment: Is the utilisateur variable located in the same component as the EditData() Method ?

Comment: Yes ser same file, just added as edit

Comment: Is there any sort of error if you use update( {nom: this.utilisateur.nom}) instead of what is written ?

Comment: FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field nom)

Comment: When you first load the page. Is the input field correctly loaded with any input?

Comment: Yes it's showing my firestore data with : [(ngModel)]="utilisateur.nom"

Comment: And after typing a new field is the utilisateur variable updated accordingly ?

Comment: No this is the problem

Comment: Did you initialize this.utilsateurs with some value before the data is recieved.